# Print Details of multiple selected list items

Tags: list, view, item

I have created a site

I would like to print multiple selected list items' details from a view (like the column names and values within)

Ultimately it would a page that already as details populated on it and these list items' details will be added to that specific page to be printed

Comment: Would the list items selected be random or would they have a repeated criteria around what you will be doing? I am trying to establish if what list items you are going to choose to print - there may be a simple way if there is a pattern of behavior.

Comment: well it will be new items on a daily basis....

Comment: it is essentially a document tracking system.... based on the recipient details, selected list items on the view, with these selected items details (like subject and date) must be extracted (like just a print screen of those ticked on the sharepoint viem) and inserted to a grid on a cover page that will be signed by the recipient that he has received those documents...

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new view displaying the criteria of the recipients and details in this view (filtering what you need) - open the view - right click - print.

Comment: This would mean for the user filtering each time......furthermore....only items that are selected (ticked), which can be more than one line item(row in the view) should be populated to a page that will be printed and that page already as a set template(which contains static information)